# Integrating spaCy with SQL Server 2022 Machine Learning Services (MLS)

Tags: sql-server, pandas, spacy, spacy-3, sql-server-2022

[SQL Server Machine Learning Services (MLS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver16) facilitates running Python and R scripts directly within the SQL Server engine.

[This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-python-train-score-model?view=sql-server-ver16) explains how to store a trained model as `VARBINARY` in a table and execute a model against it, with the results appearing as sql server resultset rows (via `pandas` dataframes).

I'm trying to integrate spaCy with MLS, as we have a wealth of text data sitting in a DB and it seems much easier (for a spaCy PoC) to generate textcat results directly within the DB instead of building an integration with APIs etc.

I'm running into some issues:

- `spacy.load()` takes a path to a directory, however, the approach in the tutorial assumes the entire model and all dependencies are stored in a single `VARBINARY` blob
- There are various tutorials relating to running [SQL MLS with `ONNX` models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/deploy-onnx). Does spaCy support this?
- I can't entirely figure out how to get my text from SQL to `spaCy` with `pandas` in the middle as I haven't used pandas before.

Does anyone in the community have any pointers? Is it technically feasible? Any working sample code to point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Technically `spacy.load()` takes a `Path`-like object, so if you're committed to storing your model and configuration in a single `VARBINARY` blob you'll have to implement a subclass of `Path` that hides away all those implementation details. But that's somewhat beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Is it just 2 files? The model and the config file? If so perhaps I could store them as 2 separate `VARBINARY` blobs and have spacy load them individually - is that feasible? PS I'm new to both spaCy and Python (seasoned JS/SQL developer here), so sorry if my questions are very newbie!

Comment: I've done a bit more reading up on things and am wondering if `pickle` can help with my Use Case?